# What can I do with an inconsistent column delimited text file?

Tags: csv

I have a text file that looks something like...

```
firstname:middle:lastname
firstname:middle:lastname
firstname:lastname
firstname:middle:lastname
firstname:lastname
```

I would like to be able to eventually use this information in a MySQL database, but since the columns are not correct I am not sure what to do. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you planning to use any scripting language to put this data into a database, if yes, which one?

Comment: If I do use one, PHP would be the best. I am totally open to an option like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you have is only the above variations, then you can make the assumptions:

> First part is the firstname
>
> Last part is the lastname

Therefore if using PHP for example you could use `explode` to separate the data on the delimeter such as in this case being `:`.

When looping through each row just assume the last part is the lastname, first part is the firstname and the middle part is the middlename.

You can use `count()` to find out how many parts are in the specific row you are reading inside the loop. This should allow you to figure out which one is the last part.

Comment: OK well looking at the data there is anywhere from 10-15 columns... That kinda changes things... Sorry about that. Does this still work with the explode?

Comment: OK I will look into the explode and count functions. Thanks so much!!

Comment: You should still be able to use explode however I would need to see a fuller sample of the data. Have all the additional columns got data in every column?

Comment: No Some columns have data and some do not. The first 5 columns have consistent data though. After that some do and some do not. The columns do have a qualifier before them. So it looks like this `name:bob,middle:e,last:brown` Is there any way to use that to use that to put that information into a variable, and if it is not there then use `NULL` or the likes instead?

Comment: That is workable if it states what type of data it is. Use explode twice, once on the comma delimiter to put all the columns into an array. Then again on the colon delimiter to get the column name. This should then allow you to place the data into the database under the correct columns.

Comment: It took me awhile to get it formatted and working correctly but this works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is so simple ... the solution is trivial

```
firstname:middle:lastname
firstname:lastname

if(there are only two columns) { that means we have first and last name }
else { we have first, middle and last name }
```

If there are more columns, you could maybe resolve data to proper columns if you manage to build a priority list (like in what order they could be missing, for example 'last name > first name > middle name') or/and if you could combine that with data type matching (string/int/double/date) ... anyway you need to gather all your domain knowledge and see if that suffice.

Comment: OK well looking at the data there is anywhere from 10-15 columns... That kinda changes things... Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention the qualifiers at first. You can easily identify data by those qualifiers then.